# Tangent curve is geodesic on unit sphere

Tags: differential-geometry, geodesic

I wonder if some one can help me with the following problem:

> Let $\gamma: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}^3$ be a regular curve
>   parametrized by arclength. Show that if the tangent curve
>   $\dot{\gamma}: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}^3$ is a non-constant geodesic
>   on the unit sphere $S^2$, then the curvature $\kappa$ and torsion
>   $\tau$ are constant.

If $\dot{\gamma}$ is a non-constant geodesic on $S^2$, then its second derivative $\gamma^{(3)}$, satisfies $\lVert \gamma^{(3)} \rVert^{\text{tan}}=0$ (it's tangential part is 0). Then it must be parallel to the normal (which on the unit sphere is just the coordinate) so $\gamma^{(3)}=r (x,y,z)$ for some $r$. Is this correct? If yes, how can I proceed from here?

Comment: You reasoning so far seems correct. Now try calculating $\frac{d \kappa}{d t}$.

Comment: Thanks! I don't see how to do that...?

Comment: What is $\kappa$, if your curve is parametrised by arclength? It just is $\kappa=\|\ddot{\gamma}\|$.

Comment: Right, $\frac{d \kappa}{dt}=\lVert \gamma^{(3)} \rVert= r$ ?

Comment: No. Your goal should be $\frac{d \kappa}{d t}=0$, because this would give you $\kappa=constant$. Write down $\|\ddot{\gamma}\|$ explicitly: $\|\ddot{\gamma}\|=\sqrt{(\ddot{\gamma}^1)^2+(\ddot{\gamma}^2)^2+(\ddot{\gamma}^3)^2}$. You have forgotten to apply the chain rule.

Comment: Maybe the calculation is easier if you derive $\kappa^2=\langle \ddot{\gamma},\ddot{\gamma}\rangle$ instead. Here $\langle\cdot,\cdot\rangle$ is the euclidean scalar product.

Comment: Ok! $\frac{d\kappa}{dt}= \frac{d}{dt} \langle \ddot{\gamma},\ddot{\gamma}\rangle= 2\langle \ddot{\gamma},\gamma^{(3)}\rangle=0$ since $\dot{\gamma}$ is a geodesic and the tangential part of $\gamma^{(3)}$ is 0...?

Comment: Yes, you got it.